# How to allow empty Custom Fields?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I found Custom Fields in WordPress as really good helper, I don't have any problems with checking whether the Custom Field is or is not empty so I can show it or hide it. But there's a big BUT:

**Problem:** WordPress 3.5.2. doesn't allow empty Custom Fields (not in default behaviour),
and user is not a database of the meta names he can use - so I want to preset the names for the user - some names will have empty value... so...

**The Question is:** how to allow empty Custom Fields? Or how to disable the WP empty check?

**EDIT:** The english error message is "Please provide a custom field value."

**EDIT2:** I am looking for a solution that allows empty Custom Field not using some placeholder instead - just to be clear.

**So if you don't mind having some placeholder your solution would be:**
1) add a word like "nothing" as value
2) then check:

```
if( trim($meta)=="nothing" ) { /* code for "empty" value */ }
   else { /* code for "non-empty" value */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this plugin for Advance Custom Field.

[Advance Custom Field](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

Please download it and check.